# How to copy the value of a custom field from sale order to invoice while creating invoice in odoo

Tags: odoo-8

I have a custom field in `sale.order.line` as

```
scheme = fields.Many2one('scheme')
```

Same as this, A field is also there in `account.invoice.line` as,

```
scheme = fields.Many2one('scheme')
```

While converting sale order to invoice, I want to copy the value from `sale.order.line` to `account.inovice.line`.
How can I do this?

I tried overriding the function(which is called while clicking on create invoice button) in an inherited class, but the function is not executing. How can I do this?

I tried something like this but the function is not executing..

```
def _prepare_advance_invoice_vals(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    ......
    .....

        # create the invoice
        inv_line_values = {
            'name': res.get('name'),
            'origin': sale.name,
            'account_id': res['account_id'],
            'price_unit': inv_amount,
            'quantity': wizard.qtty or 1.0,
            'discount': False,
            'uos_id': res.get('uos_id', False),
            'product_id': wizard.product_id.id,
            'invoice_line_tax_id': res.get('invoice_line_tax_id'),
            'account_analytic_id': sale.project_id.id or False,
            'scheme':sale.scheme,
        }
        inv_values = {
            'name': sale.client_order_ref or sale.name,
            'origin': sale.name,
            'type': 'out_invoice',
            'reference': False,
            'account_id': sale.partner_id.property_account_receivable.id,
            'partner_id': sale.partner_invoice_id.id,
            'invoice_line': [(0, 0, inv_line_values)],
            'currency_id': sale.pricelist_id.currency_id.id,
            'comment': sale.note,
            'payment_term': sale.payment_term.id,
            'fiscal_position': sale.fiscal_position.id or sale.partner_id.property_account_position.id,
            'section_id': sale.section_id.id,
            'scheme':sale.scheme,(custom field)
        }
        result.append((sale.id, inv_values))
    return_value = super(account_advance_inv, self)._prepare_advance_invoice_vals(result)
    return return_value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override **_prepare_invoice_line** method from sale.py in sale module.

```
    @api.multi
    def _prepare_invoice_line(self, qty):
        ...

        ...
        res = {
            'name': self.name,
            'sequence': self.sequence,
            'origin': self.order_id.name,
            'account_id': account.id,
            'price_unit': self.price_unit,
            'quantity': qty,
            'discount': self.discount,
            'uom_id': self.product_uom.id,
            'product_id': self.product_id.id or False,
            'invoice_line_tax_ids': [(6, 0, self.tax_id.ids)],
            'account_analytic_id': self.order_id.project_id.id,
            'scheme' : self.scheme.id
        }
        return res
```

Add your field in res dictionary as shown in above code.

Comment: @Ileash.. I tried with overriding the function. But it is not executing. What may be the problem. I have updated the code